# Sharing DDR3 memory between two sources

Tags: ddr3, sharedbus

I have an FPGA and a powerful ARM processor both support DDR3. I am an experienced designer for smaller more embedded designs with less powerful CPUs but this is my first rodeo with a powerful ARM and FPGAs. I am trying to figure out if I could share the DDR3 between the processor and FPGA so that I can use the memory as a way to communicate between the two. I need to shift large amounts of data between the two. Also, this would simplify(?) my design and save cost. I don't know what is the feasibility of this.

Comment: You would need dual-ported DDR3 RAM - which means two independent interfaces. I don't think such chips exist - I have only found dual ported SRAM chips so far.

Comment: I'm not sure how possible/feasible this is, but it sounds like you should look into using a DMA engine to transfer memory between the two so that they can both access the same info. You'd likely still need two separate dimms or at least a virtual split in the memory space.

Comment: Could you maybe construct an access interface in the fpga through which the processor may talk to the ram?

Comment: @TurboJ *Theoretically*, the RAM would not have to be dual-ported; a form of time slicing could be used. In addition to the fact that common memory controllers do not support such, adding a load to the interface would reduce the peak frequency. I would guess that [HL-SDK's suggestion](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/112941/#comment-226912) of using a communication interface between the devices would be a good way to proceed. If the processor has I/O cache coherence, using the processor's memory could avoid cache writeback/flush instructions.

Comment: Can you elaborate this....why u want to use memory as an interface to communicate between FPGA and ARM.There are specific interfaces we can use to commjnicate between them...it is very un feasible that too at DDR3 speeds. Or you are storing data in DDR3 using FPGA and read it again with ARM...Then u need to have switches to be controlled for few lines based on CKE line....

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the SoC and Zync devices from Altera and Xilinx. These chips offer ARM9 processors merged with FPGA fabric. This allows you to setup a single DDR3 interface, but have both the FPGA and CPU's access it via internal multi-port DDR3 controllers.

[Cyclone V SoCs: Lowest System Cost and Power](http://www.altera.com/devices/processor/soc-fpga/cyclone-v-soc/cyclone-v-soc.html)

[Zynq-7000 All Programmable SoC](http://www.xilinx.com/products/silicon-devices/soc/zynq-7000/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to answer this. I can not answer how to do this one way, that is to have two devices in parallel access the ram. That is a question of several things in that of itself. There is the E.E. of it, DDR3 uses differential pairs and operates at high speeds such that capacitance, interference, and impedance need to be addressed by adding another branch to any differential pair. It very well could be that doubling the length of the traces by having 2 devices may increase the capacitance past the limit spelled out by the DDR3 specification, a requirement for it's high speed.

Then there is the question of if the fixed memory controllers can work with it. You may not have a lot of room for customization, and as one com-mentor said, you might have to run at excessively low rates to allow it. Basically the speed of the clock for the DDR3 bus would have to be twice the access speed of the two devices so that they can interleave their access with out interfering with each other. Also the speed at which a transaction actually takes to perform is lower, so they operate on a "buffer" to keep up that through put. The latency may introduce race conditions too which software would have to account for.

The other solution I can think of is to have the FPGA a pci device, then the CPU will have some of the ram as DMA for the FPGA. The FPGA simply need access the ram through the PCI bus which is common.